# mySql- error when i import data from a file

Tags: mysql

Here is my table, i write it in a procedure.

```
create table if not exists Tabela_veche(
         Data Int,
          Ora Int,
          NumeAng Varchar(30),
          PrenumeAng Varchar(30) ,
          NumeSef Varchar(30),
          PrenumeSef Varchar(30),
          NrPiese int(255)
         )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

here i am trying to populate the columns

```
set global local_infile = 1;
     LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/fisier.txt'
INTO TABLE Tabela_veche
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'    
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 lines
(Data, Ora, NumeAng, PrenumeAng, NumeSef, PrenumeSef, NrPiese);
```

My file "fisiers.txt" looks like this (first line):

```
Data     Ora    NumeAng PrenumeAng  NumeSef PrenumeSef  NrPiese

12062016    013103  Algren  Steve   Kolbe   Ed  180
```

And my error is

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '12062016 0' for column 'Data' at row 1.

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be Datat instead of Data ?

Comment: i don't understand why i have this 0 in the end.

Comment: I created a table as per your statement and txt file with three records and loading completed fine.

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/\projects/\fisiers.txt' 
INTO TABLE Tabela_veche
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 lines
(Datat, Ora, NumeAng, PrenumeAng, NumeSef, PrenumeSef, NrPiese);
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 18 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 18

Did you ran outside procedure and see, if it works ?

Comment: it doesn't work. i tried with FIELDS TERMINATED BY '    ' (with 3 spaces) and now i have this: Error Code: 1261. Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns –

Comment: work data is used as reserved word. Can you change "Data" to "Data_something" and retry again.

Comment: Few more mistakes, i see
1) the load is having wrong file name. It should be fisiers.txt not fisier.txt
2) Use a space between '' in fields termination 
Example:
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '